# NodeJS Api Response Request From Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have request table in mysql. there are 3 column id, json and ip. want to start js background and it will check new rows and generate axios request. I looked everywhere but I could find solution. Example table like below.

ID Json IP
1  {"a":"b"} 192.168.1.1

Script will get api request after finish axios request it will delete row.

just I could connect mysql like code below

```
    var async = require("async");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'x'
});



connection.query("SELECT * FROM x", function(err, rows, fields) {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    console.log(row.id);
  });
  console.log('Finish');
},0);
```

Comment: Let me ask a few questions before providing an answer:
1. Do you want to constantly check the DB, or this is a one time thing, e.g. when you check the rows in the database, send request, delete the rows, the application should close and exit?
2. When you say you want to do it in the background, do you mean as a background process or you want to continue with the application while the requests are executing asynchronously?

Comment: actually I want it nodejs script as service.